# Change size of text according to screen width in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want the text size to remain the same however i want it to be bigger when on a larger screen width device.

```
MediaQueryData queryData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    Text("Hello.",
        style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: queryData.size.width, color: Colors.white),
 ),

}
```

However, it became so big when i tried queryData.size.width. in this case i want the text to expand according to different devices screens.

[image: left: ipad, right: iphone X]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 10):

You just need to multiply the result from the media query by a constant.

```
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
return Text(
  "Hello.",
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: width * 0.2,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a class named sizeconfig:

```
  class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double blockSizeHorizontal;
  static double blockSizeVertical;

  static double _safeAreaHorizontal;
  static double _safeAreaVertical;
  static double safeBlockHorizontal;
  static double safeBlockVertical;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    blockSizeHorizontal = screenWidth / 100;
    blockSizeVertical = screenHeight / 100;

    _safeAreaHorizontal =
        _mediaQueryData.padding.left + _mediaQueryData.padding.right;
    _safeAreaVertical =
        _mediaQueryData.padding.top + _mediaQueryData.padding.bottom;
    safeBlockHorizontal = (screenWidth - _safeAreaHorizontal) / 100;
    safeBlockVertical = (screenHeight - _safeAreaVertical) / 100;
  }
}
```

And in your page initialize this class using SizeConfig().init(context)
then on your fontsize :SizeConfig.screenWidth * .02.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is relevant also for Containers, Buttons, etc... So I suggest you to check how [this](https://github.com/o1298098/Flutter-Movie) amazing open source (using the alibaba redux) solved this issue using an [utility-adapter](https://github.com/o1298098/Flutter-Movie/blob/master/lib/actions/adapt.dart) file in several places like in the [account](https://github.com/o1298098/Flutter-Movie/blob/master/lib/views/account_page/components/header_component/view.dart) header page.

Another excellent option is to check the [flutter-screen-util](https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_screenutil) dependency, they have a good example there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) to set font size responsive to any screen layout also with this package you can make your other widgets responsive by its setWidth() and setHeight() methods,
You can check its documentation here : [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil)

Answer (score -17):

We can use view vw and vh unit to provide font-size, which will make your text more visible with different viewport size.

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}


1vw = 1% of viewport width
1vh = 1% of viewport height
1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger
```